# jni doesn't find method in inner class , java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, inner-classes, nosuchmethoderror

I have a question for getting access to methods in nested classes with JNI.

```
public class AccountUI {
    public native ExtrasWageUI[] getExtrasWages();

      public class ExtrasWageUI {
        public ExtrasWageUI() {
          mCppHandle = callConstructorN();
        }

        public ExtrasWageUI(long cppHandle) {
          mCppHandle = cppHandle;
        }

      private native long callConstructorN();
   }
  }
```

I will get the Error at `accountUI.getExtrasWages()`:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no method with name='' signature='(J)V' in class
>   Lde/projects/customer/.../myProject/domain/AccountUI$ExtrasWageUI;

JNI won´t find the method.
Has anyone an idea how I can access the method in the inner class?

Comment: Correction. It *does* find the class. It doesn't find the *method.* When writing JNI method signatures, don't make them up yourself. Use the output of `javap -s`. It's never wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add the outer class in the signature:

```
environment->GetMethodID(resultClassAssistantUI, "<init>", "(L.../domain/AccountUI;J)V");
```